# How do I go about learning the Najdorf Sicilian?

Tags: opening, sicilian-defense, najdorf

I want to play and learn the Najdorf Sicilian.  I know that white has three main options:

6.Bg5
6.Be3
6.Bc4

But I don't know much more than that.  Furthermore, I want to play the Open Sicilian as white and against the Najdorf play 6.Bg5, so I think for me it's worth learning these variations.

Should I get Starting Out: Najdorf Sicilian?

Comment: [This link](http://www.chess.com/forum/view/chess-openings/best-book-for-najdorf-as-black) might be useful for the question on the book "Starting Out: Najdorf Sicilian" (it also contains comments on some other popular Najdorf books).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably(I haven't read it) , other options are a video series eg

https://chess24.com/en/learn/advanced/video/a-complete-najdorf-repertoire/najdorf-introduction

or a more detailed book eg

http://www.qualitychess.co.uk/products/1/49/grandmaster_repertoire_6_-_the_sicilian_defence_by_lubomir_ftacnik/

or

https://www.newinchess.com/The_Sharpest_Sicilian_2012-p-1523.html.

In general I would recommend the Starting Out repertoires for anyone under 2000 FIDE.

Comment: Yeah, I am in the 1400's USCF

Comment: Also, if you are 1400 USCF I would definitely recommend a Starting Out book but also trying to find whatever model games you can, maybe Fischer's to start with.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this site.  Do you think the chess24 video series would be too advanced for me?  Is it good?

Comment: It is pretty good, I'm not sure if it is too advanced or not to be honest. The presenters are usually pretty clear.

Comment: Yeah, and that girl is kinda hot, lol